# Cannot select a selectbox

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am on the website [Click Here](https://www.mister-auto.com/)

And I would like to grab the brand of the vehicle using selenium and HTML5 attribute:

My code is below:

```
WebElement element=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//element[@data-selenium='select_model_brand']"));
Select option=new Select(element);
option.selectByValue("88");
```

However, nothing happens, do you know where the problem is?

Comment: Please share block of HTML

Comment: Update the question with the _Manual Steps_ you are trying to automate along with your code trials.

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple click action on dropdown and once dropdown is visible, Clicking `By.cssLocator("[ng-model='brand_id'] option[value=88]")` will take you there.

Answer (score 0):

With the limited information in the question, it looks to me like your selector is broken.  When I execute it in chrome dev tools on the site provided, I get no results.

I do however get some results using the following css selector, for what I assume are the select elements are you are trying to select

`("div.select div:nth-child(2) select")`

As there are 3 select elements in the page just update the nth-child selector to find the one you want